# How to compute $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X^2Y^2)]$ when $(X,Y)\sim N(0,\Sigma)$?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, expectation

I'm trying to compute the following quantities

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(X^2Y^2)],~\mathbb{E}[\exp(X^4)],~~\text{and}~\mathbb{E}[\exp(XY^2)]
\end{align}
where $(X,Y)\sim N(0,\Sigma)$. For simplicity, assume that the diagonal of $\Sigma$ are all ones. In particular, I'm interested in the case when $\Sigma=I_2$, the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. What is the value of the above quantities in this case? How can we compute them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\Sigma$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, here are the [related simpler questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It) you could try:

- Do you know that if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal ([**Edited**: *and* when $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix]), then they are independent?
- Can you see how things boils down to calculating 
  $
  E(\exp(X^n))?
  $
- Do you know how to get the density of $X$?
- Once one has the density $f$ of $X$, one can use
  $$
  E(g(X))=\int_\mathbb{R}g(x)f(x)\ dx.
  $$

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ being jointly normal does not imply that they are independent, which is obvious. What I'm interested is only a special case where we further assume independence.

Comment: It is assumed at the beginning of my answer that $\Sigma$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!